# How to format select query output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table like this below,

```
Type             Model       Year    
121232323        Test1       2000
121232323        Test2       2001
```

I want output like below, how to write query for that.?

```
121232323       Test1      Test2
                2000       2001
```

Comment: Where did `Originalnr` come from?

Comment: And whence is the value `2124`?

Comment: I want sql select query without passing values.

Answer (score 2):

Using Simple Pivot we can achieve

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    ( Type  int,  Model  varchar(5),  Year  int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ( Type ,  Model ,  Year )
VALUES
    (121232323, 'Test1', 2000),
    (121232323, 'Test2', 2001)
;


select Type,[Test1],[Test2] from @Table1
PIVOT (MAX(YEAR) FOR MODEL IN ([Test1],[Test2]))PVT
```

Comment: I want output like below, how to write query for that.? I want to sql select query to select dynamically with headers.
        
  Type             Model       Year 
        121232323        Test1       2000
                Test2       2001
                Test1       2000
       121232330          Test2       2001
       121232340          Test1       2000
       121232350          Test2       2001

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `Originalnr` , but you can do this with conditional aggregation if you have a limited amount of tests :

```
SELECT t.Type,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.Model = 'Test1' THEN t.Year END) as Test1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.Model = 'Test2' THEN t.Year END) as Test2
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.Type
```

Comment: I want sql select query without passing values.

Comment: I want output like below, how to write query for that.? I want to sql select query to select dynamically with headers.
        
  Type             Model       Year 
        121232323        Test1       2000
                Test2       2001
                Test1       2000
       121232330          Test2       2001
       121232340          Test1       2000
       121232350          Test2       2001

Answer (score 2):

Another method other than `PIVOT` is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Type,
    Test1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Model = 'Test1' THEN [year] END),
    Test2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Model = 'Test2' THEN [year] END)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Type
```

If you have unlimited number of `Model`s you can do it using dynamic crosstab:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql =
'SELECT
    Type' + CHAR(10) +
(SELECT DISTINCT
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN Model =''' + Model +  ''' THEN [year] END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Model) + CHAR(10)
FROM tbl
FOR XML PATH('')
) +
'FROM tbl
GROUP BY Type;';

PRINT(@sql);
EXEC(@sql);
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/490481)</kbd>

Comment: I want sql select query without passing values.

Comment: @user123 Then yuo need to do it dynamically.

Comment: how.? i need column name?

Comment: See the second part of my answer. It's done using dynamic sql.

Comment: I want output like below, how to write query for that.? I want to sql select query to select dynamically with headers.
        
  Type             Model       Year 
        121232323        Test1       2000
                Test2       2001
                Test1       2000
       121232330          Test2       2001
       121232340          Test1       2000
       121232350          Test2       2001